# Batch removal (rm -rf) just for existing directories in a subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell, batch-processing, rm

**Background:** I have written a very simple backup removal script which should delete backups that are older than three version updates.
This works by always adding the newly installed version of my software (Ghost CMS) to a txt file and all versions are located in the same directory ($GHOSTDIR/versions/3.x.y).

```
            nol=$(grep -c . ghostupgradehistory.txt)
            rl=$(echo "$(($nol-3))")
            lc=$(head -$rl ghostupgradehistory.txt)
            kv=$(tail -3 ghostupgradehistory.txt)
            dir=$(ls $GHOSTDIR/versions -d $lc 2> /dev/null)
            if [[ ${dir[@]} ]]; then echo "Delete old versions" && echo $dir && echo "Keep last three versions" && echo $kv
            cd $GHOSTDIR/versions && rm -rf $dir
            fi
```

ghostupgradehistory.txt looks like this

```
3.37.1
3.38.0
3.38.1
3.38.2
```

**The problem I have is the last command for the removal of the identified outdated versions. Instead of just deleting those it deletes the whole $GHOSTDIR/versions folder which includes even the latest version. How to fix this?**

Comment: Why don't you use find with -not -newer referencing the latest version?

Comment: I always want to keep three versions as a backup, no matter how old they are.

Comment: OK, so do the same but with latest version -3 so in your example find -not -newer *.3.38.0 -name *.versions.* -not -name *.3.38.0 -type d -delete ?

Comment: Didn't know this might have been a solution but I think the "-name *.versions." part is not correct because there is no .versions. attached to the folders: cd ghost/versions/
[versions]$ ls
3.37.1  3.38.0 3.38.1 3.38.2

Comment: Something to think about anyway.

Comment: How to define the third last version in that solution?

Comment: ls | sort | tail -4 | head -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be simple workaround, if you are sure having only directories with version names in the your `GHOSTDIR`.

First you list all directories reversed to have the newest versions on the top, then you tail the output starting on line 4. It means the 3 newest remain hidden. Finally remove them.

`ls` you can modify to sort by time `-t`, if it's more relevant or kept alphabetical sort.

```
cd $GHOSTDIR
ls -1rd */ | tail +4 | xargs rm -rf
```

or (on some builds)

```
cd $GHOSTDIR
ls -1rd */ | tail -n +4 | xargs rm -rf
```

That's it. Max 3 directories remain.

Comment: That somehow works:
                dir=$(ls $GHOSTDIR/versions -1rd */ | tail -3)
                keep=$(ls $GHOSTDIR/versions -1rd */ | head -3)
                echo "Delete old versions" && echo $dir && echo "Keep last three versions" && echo $keep
                cd $GHOSTDIR/versions && ls -1rd */ | tail -3 | xargs rm -rf but gives a strange output: Delete old versions
/home/user/ghost/versions current/ content/
Keep last three versions
versions/ /home/user/ghost/versions current/

Comment: You somehow mixing `head -X` and `tail -X`. In my post I used `tail +X`, the `+` is key here. Because `head` will not work if there is a less that expected number of version. And `tail -` works just vice-versa then `head`. You can lose some data.

Comment: That's because of the error message I receive with tail +3: 
tail: „+3“ cannot be opened for reading: file or directory not found

Comment: Aha, then it may needs different syntax e.g. on CentOS it's `tail -n +4`.